# How to customize UITableViewCell like this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I don't know how to customize `UITableViewCell` like this.
[image]

Comment: you take three lable and add into cell.also set border of lable so it looks like above

Comment: If one of these answers is the right one for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Take three `UILabel` for each `cell` of `UITableView` and give its **fram** as you need (*same as your Image)*

**1) First label should diaplay**

- court -1
- your time

**2) second label should display**

- top of right side

**3) third label display**

- bottom of right side

And make sure that you need to add all **labels** in `cell.contentView` under `cellForRowAtIndexPath` protocol method of `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom **UIViews** in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** of **UITableview** it and make changes as per your requirement..

Comment: why custom UIViews? instead you can use custom UITableViewCell

Comment: @manujmv There are hundreds of ways of doing this, i am just trying to explain one of them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create three labels in UITableViewCell
2. Give tag of label
3. In **cellForRowAtIndexPath** add label as

   ```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

   {
   NSString *cellstring =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellstring];
   if (cell == nil)
   {

   [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"TreeSafety_Cell" owner:self options:nil];
       cell=self.tbl_cell;
       self.tbl_cell=nil;

       UILable *lab_title=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];


       cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
   }
   /*-arr_TreeHazards set data in  textLabel  in tableView-*/

       [lab_title setText:[arr_TreeHazards objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

       lab_title.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

       lab_title.numberOfLines=0;

   return cell;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UITableViewCell. In e.g. `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` you create new UIViews, for example some labels. You'll have to set a backgroundcolor (`colorWithPatternImage:`). Then, just call it like you would with a normal UITableViewCell. Here's how I do it:

- Make the tableview a property of your view controller, import your custom cell, and declare a static string just below your imports: `static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";`
- In `viewDidLoad:`:

  ```
   if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:)]){
       [self.tableView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
  ```
- Here's your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

  ```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
      // Maak cell aan
      CustomCell *cell;

      // Bekijk of de nieuwste techniek gebruik kan worden, pak anders een oude techniek
      if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:)]) {
          cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
      }
      else{
          cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      }

      // Do this for < iOS 6
      if (!cell){
          cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      }

      return cell;
  }
  ```

Good luck.